# C sscanf handle white spaces

Tags: c, scanf

I have to use c sscanf to read in the line of parameters separated by ",". After I trying to add some whitespaces after the first parameter, sscanf read all following parameters as 0.

Input: 200 [space][space][space],50

my code to read in the parameters

```
size_t len = 0;
char* line = NULL;
int var1;
int var2;

getline(&line,&len, stdin)
sscanf(line, "%d,%d", &var1, &var2)
```

It turns out sscanf can read in the var1, but var2 will always be just 0.

If I delete all those white spaces, it will work.

How should I avoid those white spaces in sscanf?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @xing But I may have multiple white spaces after the first integer.